# Foreignkey and none value

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have error while try to add in ForeignKey field None value.

My model:

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    tender_game_id = models.ForeignKey(TenderGame, related_name='invoice_tender_game_id', verbose_name='Tender', blank=True, null=True)
```

makemigration/migrate/syncdb - i did all.

I'm receiving everytime error:

```
ERROR:logger:int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

What am I doing wrong?
Django 1.7

Answer (score 0):

I found error. Before insert i try type conversion int(var). If var was None i received such error.